# i want to return a timestamp without its object name like year or monthe

Tags: java, json

the result i am now getting is like this:

```
    {  
       "status":"OK",
       "message":"VEIW_SUCCESS",
       "payload":{  
          "OUTAGE0003":[  
             {  
                "startDate":{  
                   "year":2017,
                   "month":2,
                   "dayOfMonth":6,
                   "hourOfDay":0,
                   "minute":0,
                   "second":0
                },
                "endDate":{  
                   "year":2017,
                   "month":2,
                   "dayOfMonth":6,
                   "hourOfDay":17,
                   "minute":15,
                   "second":0
                }
             },


          ],
```

but what i want to output is like this:

```
     "startDate":{  
                  "time": "2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                },
                "endDate":{  
               "time": "2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                }
             },
             {  
                "startDate":{  
                    "time": "2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                },
```

i use this code to format the stringobject to jsonobject

```
return this.getGson().fromJson(stringobject,this.class);
```

final what i want to out is the output like that in above.

Comment: It depends on how you are storing the datetime. To get the output in the format you want, you need to store the datetime in that way in your java object. If you can post the java object which you are using, then it would be helpful to analyze

Comment: how your startDate and endDate objects' class is defined ? It surely has minimum 6 properties declared which are coming in json representation.  Consolidate those properties to single `Date` property and you will get desired output.

Comment: This is a  setter   public void setenddate(calander value) {
     
                  this.endDate = value;
    } with input calander datatype